# What software that I run uses AVX (or a specific assembly instruction)?

Tags: grep, binary, x86, assembly

Let's say I want to find any libraries that use AVX, or the [`VZEROALL`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/VZEROALL.html) instruction? How could I go about doing that?

I don't care if the AVX was hand written or compiled, I'll look that up later. I'm wanting to see some example code of AVX instructions (and x86-extensions) in use. Is there an instruction grep? Radare has `/c op`, but I cant find anything with this.

```
find /usr/lib -type f -name '*ssl*.so' -exec radare2 {} -qc "/c VZEROALL" \;
```

Is there anything I can use to check Radare? Or scan executable sections in ELFs for a specific instruction?

**Not this isn't really programming question. It's more like a binary-`grep` for instruction question.**

Comment: You can use a normal text-based grep if you have a disassembler

Answer (score 2):

Radare2 accepts assembly commands in lower case only. The following should work (albeit is not guaranteed to return any results):

```
find /usr/lib -type f -name '*ssl*.so' -exec radare2 {} -qc "/c vzeroall" \;
```

It's also possible to look up assembly commands using `objdump`. In that case your example would look like this:

```
find /usr/lib -type f -name '*ssl*.so' -exec bash -c 'objdump -d "$0" | grep -iq vzeroall' {} \; -print
```

One advantage of this approach would be the ability to specify the desired assembly instructions as ordinary regular expressions.